# How to add repos in the list of indexed repo in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-central

After, I have imported a project in Intellij IDEA, It couldn't resolve any dependance.
because in Settings -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Repositories in the Indexed Maven Repositories, it has only the local repo.
So, How can I add the Maven Central Repository?

Comment: Have you got the right maven settings? Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Build Tools->Maven
Especially maven home, user settings file and local repo

Comment: they are on default settings

Comment: well, the default settings did not work for me, try to set the directories manually (tick the override checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

That must be because you don't have maven correctly configured.

Verify if you have the correct configuration in your

> /.m2/settings.xml

For more info see

> http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: I only have a proxies section in the settings.xml

Comment: In the maven settings (in idea) did he find the maven home directory, user settings and local repository correctly?
Can you execute any maven command in the command line or terminal?